# QML: QtQuick Extension Plugin - What is URI?

Tags: application-development, qt, ubuntu-sdk, qml, qt-creator

When starting a new Qt Quick Extension Plugin, it asks me to specify Object Class Name (Easy enough), but also something called URI.

1. What does URI stand for?
2. What does this project need URI for?
3. Does my project depend on URI, or is optional?
4. What do its components, "com" . "mycompany" . "qmlcomponents" reference?
5. How do I configure its components to match my setup?

[image: URI]

Comment: URI = Uniform resource identifier http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Qt Quick2 Extension Plugin](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qqmlextensionplugin.html) is a C++ plugin that makes it possible to offer extensions that can be loaded dynamically into applications using the [QQmlEngine](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qqmlengine.html) class.

To make it possible to query at run-time whether a plugin implements a given interface, you must use the [Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtplugin.html#Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE) macro. The first argument is the name of the interface. The second argument is a string identifying the interface in a **unique** way, the URI.

By convention, Qt use a [Java package name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package#Package_naming_conventions) syntax to identify interfaces, hence the "com.mycompany.qmlcomponents" schema.

Source: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-plugandpaint-example.html